# Limit number of checked boxes in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am working on www.peelcarsales.com using automotive theme on wordpress. On its pre-owned page(http://peelcarsales.com/inventory/) I want to limit the number of checked boxes checked at a time to maximum 4. Kindly help me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write Javascript in the page that loads your form. Every time you check a box, you count whether the maximum is 4 already. If it is, you undo the check and give a warning.

Alternatively, you could disable all unchecked checkboxes as soon as you reach 4 checkboxes.

Either way the solution is clientside Javascript. It has nothing to do with PHP or Wordpress.

If you do not want to modify the files themselves, you could use a third-party plugin to manipulate headers and footers... This one for instance will let you add Javascript to a header: https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-and-footer-scripts/

Comment: David I am working on wordpress dashboard . I cannot update the files from editor as when theme would be updated the changes made in the java-script file would be nullified. Kindly recommend a good plugin to add javascript code to wordpress site